# Ansible Dynamic Inventory groups not working

Tags: ansible

I'm working with the ec2 dynamic inventory script for ansible, and have created a fairly simply proof of concept. This is the content of the `groups` file, which exists next to `ec2.py` and `ec2.ini`:

```
[tag_classification_server_type_1]

[app_servers:children]
tag_classification_server_type_1

[stage:children]
app_servers

[stage:vars]
environment_name = stage
```

When I use that inventory to ping the tag groups, it works as expected:

```
$>ansible -i inventory/stage/ec2.py tag_classification_server_type_1 -m ping --private-key ~/.ssh/foo.pem 
12.345.67.89 | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false, 
    "ping": "pong"
}
```

But attempting to use the defined groups fails (I'm showing `stage` here, but the same output is true when attempting to communicate with the `app_servers` group):

```
$>ansible -i inventory/stage/ec2.py stage -m ping --private-key ~/.ssh/foo.pem
 [WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: stage

 [WARNING]: No hosts matched, nothing to do
```

I've used groups in ansible using ec2 before, and never had any problems. I downloaded completely fresh `ec2.ini` and `ec2.py` files to make sure I hadn't accidentally modified them.

When I check the inventory `ansible-inventory ec2.py --list`, it confirms that my defined groups aren't there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Naturally, if you struggle with a problem for an hour, you'll get nowhere. But post on StackOverflow, and you'll figure it out yourself in 5 minutes.

Ends up you have to pass the entire folder containing `groups` and `ec2.py` and `ec2.ini` if you want it to respect the `groups` - otherwise it ignores them.

So the correct call is:

```
$>ansible -i inventory/stage stage -m ping --private-key ~/.ssh/foo.pem
```

Instead of:

```
$>ansible -i inventory/stage/ec2.py stage -m ping --private-key ~/.ssh/foo.pem
```